# periodic numbers in every basis

Tags: elementary-number-theory

We know that a number that is periodic in base $10$ does not need to be periodic in base $2$ for example.

My question is if there are numbers that are periodic in every possible base.

The non existence of such numbers would imply that periodicity is not a property of numbers but in the way we represent them.

Comment: What do you mean by "periodic"?

Comment: 3.134513451345.... for example

Comment: Recurring decimals, oh wait, I can't say "decimal"

Comment: $0.0000\ldots$ is trivially periodic in every base.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By periodic number, I see you mean a number with a decimal expansion which repeats itself, so $0.\overline{a_1a_2a_3\dots a_n}$ (without loss of generality, we can only look at the numbers on $(0,1)$, since any number equals $x=k+y$ where $k\in\mathbb Z$ and $y\in(0,1)$ is periodic iff $x$ is periodic).

The problem is this: every number which has a periodic decimal expansion (in *any* base) must necesarily be a fraction. You can prove this using the same technique that works in base $10$.

This means that $x = \frac{a}{b}$ for some $a<b\in\mathbb N$. However, this also means that in base $b$, the value of $x$ can be written as (if $a<b$) $$0.a$$ (where $a$ is a single digit in base $b$) and it is not periodic.

Comment: Isn't $0.a$ really periodic, as written $0.a0000...$?

Comment: In that case, every rational number is periodic, of course. But for me, the number $0$ for example is *not* periodic. In decimal, for example, I consider $\frac13$ periodic, while $\frac12$ is not periodic, would you not agree?

Comment: Yes. If one allows "ultimately periodic" then rationals are periodic in any base as you say, so the question should require the periodic part begins immediately after the "decimal" point. [However with this definition $0$ would be periodic.]

Comment: A repeating or recurring decimal is a way of representing rational numbers in arithmetic. The decimal representation of a number is said to be repeating if it becomes periodic (repeating its values at regular intervals) and the infinitely-repeated digit is not zero. (quoted from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal)

Comment: Good. That definition rules out $0.000...$ and makes your argument work (+1).

Comment: Well, it's a matter of deffinition. Either my argument proves that there are no numbers that are periodic in all bases or it proves that for each rational number, there exists some base in which it has a expansion with only zeroes at the end.

Comment: @5xum Please note that in every integer base $b \geq 2$, every non-zero number with a finite expansion [admits a periodic representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...#Generalizations) (with your definition), much like $1 = 0.\overline{9}$ in decimal notation.